# Can't use global variables with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I have a file like this:

```
char* vidmem = (char*)0xb8000;

int main()
{
    vidmem[0] = 'x';
    vidmem[1] = 0x0f;
}
```

But when i compile it with gcc it behave like vidmem does not even exist. I have this problem with all variable declared outside of function. Maby this one can be declare inside main but other variables in other files linked to this can't be.
This how I compile it:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.obj -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -m64
```

And this is how i assemble all the files:

```
gcc -m64 -Wl,--build-id=none -static -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -lgcc main.obj [..] -T linker.ld -o out.bin
```

Why this happen? And how can i solve it?

**EDIT:**

I am making an OS and this is the code from the C kernel. I am using linux subsystem for windows to compile it and qemu for testing

Here is a link to all the code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/7x21lh4dnc93dz9/OS.7z/file

Comment: "it behave like vidmem does not even exist" how so? What exact behavior are you seeing?

Comment: How about `volatile char* vidmem = (char*)0xb8000;` ? BTW, what is your platform? Looks like you are compiling it as a bare-metal

Comment: @EugeneSh. nope..

Comment: @BrennanVincent when i run this code i expect a 'x' printed to the screen in the up left corner but i see nothing. When instead i move the variable declaration inside the main function it works

Comment: @Mimmo *i expect a 'x' printed to the screen in the up left corner*  Why do you expect that?  That's a **very** platform-dependent expectation, and you've left that out entirely.

Comment: Are you running MS-DOS on a 8086 PC?

Comment: @AndrewHenle ok i haven't specified that this is the code for an OS kernel and that address (0xB8000) is the address of the screen in memory (VGA) so by putting the 0th element to 'x' i specify the character and the 1st to 0x0f i specify the color

Comment: "it behave like vidmem does not even exist" - implies you should get a compilation error on `vidmem` being an undefined symbol.

Comment: @goodvibration No! it exist but even if i modidy it nothing appen to the program

Comment: Please add: [mcve], your platform and environment description, your expected results, your actual results. Optional, but recommended - assembly code generated by the compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you want but this code is called by lot of other asm files that prepare the OS enviroment. do i have to anyway?

Comment: I would debug the program and check the value of `vidmem`. Perhaps the initialization of the data section (bss) isn't added to the executable image, in which case it remains in its default state (all zeros), hence this variable probably points to address zero, and as a result, your code in `main` doesn't impact the screen, which is mapped to a different address.

Comment: Do you have some sort of startup code? From the compile command it looks like you don't.  the load section supposed to be corresponding to the execution section? If not, then the startup code has to *copy* the data section to the execution region, otherwise your globals will be uninitialized.

Comment: I am prepareing a git repository to link and download all the code that call this so not to post all here

Comment: An OS kernel doesn't normally start with `main`. You need your own startup code. `-m64` and "vidmem at 0xb8000" don't go togetger very well. Are you following some kind of kernel writing tutorial?

Comment: @n.m. Yes i've followed the one from theMike97_ then when the playlist is ended i've switched to C the last part that was exatly the same in asm

Comment: Nobody is going to download a `.7z` archive file. Post the code as code, or if relevant, as some sort of source repo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare global variables but you have to initialize inside main like this:
char* vidmem;

```
char* vidmem;

int main()
{
    vidmem = (char*)0xb8000;

    vidmem[0] = 'x';
    vidmem[1] = 0x0f;
}
```

Comment: This is not explaining what is wrong and why, but gives a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there are so many down votes to this question. This is a totally valid and interesting question and I just ran into the same problem 1 hour ago.

The problem is that in a normal scenario when the linker is generating an executable to run on Linux, for example, the global variables are stored in the .data section, and their values are part of the executable. Now, in your scenario, you are generating raw binary data and directly booting it. In this case, you need to specify to the linker where the global variables should be stored in the image. You can do it via `-Tdata 0x6000` to store them starting at address 0x6000, for example. Then, when loading your OS, be sure to load this part of the image to memory, before accessing the global variable.